# No Module Found lxml

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I am running on El Capitan 10.11.6, and when I try to run my program.py file, I keep on getting this error:

```
XXX-Air:test darthvader$ ./program.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./program.py", line 6, in <module>
from lxml import html
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

When I tried to pip install the lxml, I kept on getting this:

```
XXX-Air:test darthvader$ pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Why do I still get the Import Error?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment which doesn't have it installed?

Comment: Can you share the first line of `program.py` please?

Comment: Yes I am in a virtual environment (flask virtualenv), but I have no clue how to check or even import into a virtual environment.

Comment: @Mureinik sure its another import: 'from flask import Flask, jsonify'

Comment: @Katserbot the very first line. Should be something that starts with a `#!`.

Comment: @Mureinik sorry! :  `#!flask/bin/python`

Comment: you need to tell your file what interpreter it should use, in general it is #!/usr/bin/python when you are using a system package. But you're saying you are using a virtualenv, so "python program.py" should work